# webrtc each step success but no video share

Tags: webrtc

chrome version: 62.0.3202.94;
firefox version: 57.0.1;

I write a simple demo use webrtc and socket.io.
It works with pages. For example, I open one page to connect socket, and waiting for `PeerConnection` info from the main page(which get the local media). When I open the main, I create `ice` and `sdp` and then exchange them by `socket.io` to create connection. 
Here is the code.

```js
// The server side:
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.get('/phone', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/phone.html')
})

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
let clients = []

io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  clients.push(socket)
  const referer = socket.handshake.headers.referer
  
  // socket connect from '/phone'
  if (referer.match('/phone')) {
    // send the ice from phone to others
    socket.on('phone_ice_candidate', function(res) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('pc_add_ice', {
        ice: res.ice
      })
    })

    // send the sdp from phone to others
    socket.on('send_phone_sdp', function(data) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('set_pc_remote_sdp', {
        desc: data.desc
      })
    })
  }

  // phone add ice from web
  socket.on('remote_ice_candidate', function(ice) {
    socket.to(getId(clients, '/phone')).emit('send_ice_to_pc', {
      ice: ice
    })
  })

  // phone add sdp from web
  socket.on('send_pc_sdp', function(data) {
    // send to phone
    socket.to(getId(clients, '/phone')).emit('set_phone_remote_sdp', {
      desc: data
    })
  })

  // socket disconnect and remove it from clients
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    let id = socket.id
    clients.forEach((client, index) => {
      if (client.id === id) {
        clients.splice(index, 1)
      }
    })
  })
})

// get the socket id to emit
function getId(sockets, exp) {
  let id
  sockets.forEach(socket => {
    if (socket.handshake.headers.referer.match(exp)) {
      id = socket.id
    }
  })
  return id
}

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('port listening at 3000')
})
```

```js
// --------------------------------------------- //
// web.js
var socket = io();
var server = {
    // "iceServers": [{
    //     "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
    // }]
  },
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null),
  v = document.querySelector('#video2')
// web onicecandidate
pc.onicecandidate = function(event) {
  if (event.candidate) {
    socket.emit('remote_ice_candidate', {
      ice: event.candidate
    })
  }
}
// web addIceCandidate
socket.on('pc_add_ice', function(event) {
  pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.ice))
})

// didn't trigger
pc.ontrack = function(e) {
  // v.srcObject = e.streams[0];
  console.log(e, 'pc.ontrack')
}

// web setRemoteDescription and createAnswer
socket.on('set_pc_remote_sdp', function(e) {
  pc.setRemoteDescription(e.desc).then(
    function() {
      console.log('remote setRemoteDescription success')

      pc.createAnswer().then(function(desc) {
        pc.setLocalDescription(desc).then(
          function() {
            socket.emit('send_pc_sdp', {
              desc: desc
            })
          },
          function(err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
        );
      })
    },
    function() {
      console.log('pc setLocalDescription error')
    }
  )

})

// web iceConnectionState
pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function() {
  console.log('web oniceconnectionstatechange', pc.iceConnectionState)
  // log  checking -> connected
};
```

```js
//---------------------------------------------//
// phone.js
var socket = io();
var server = {
    // "iceServers": [{
    //     "url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"
    // }]
  },
  pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null),
  v = document.querySelector('#video1')


// phone onicecandidate
pc.onicecandidate = function(event) {
  if (event.candidate) {
    socket.emit('phone_ice_candidate', {
      ice: event.candidate
    })
  }
}

// phone addIceCandidate
socket.on('send_ice_to_pc', function(event) {
  pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(event.ice.ice))
})

// getUserMedia
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {
      width: 400,
      height: 300
    },
    audio: false
  })
  .then(function(stream) {
    v.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    pc.addStream(stream);
  })
  .then(function() {
    // create offer
    pc.createOffer({
      offerToReceiveVideo: 1
    }).then(function(e) {
      // pc setLocalDescription
      pc.setLocalDescription(e).then(
        function() {
          socket.emit('send_phone_sdp', {
            desc: e
          })
        },
        function() {
          console.log('pc setLocalDescription error')
        }
      )
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
  })

// phone setRemoteDescription
socket.on('set_phone_remote_sdp', function(e) {
  pc.setRemoteDescription(e.desc.desc).then(
    function() {
      console.log('pc setRemoteDescription success')
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
})
// phone iceConnectionState
pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = function() {
  console.log('phone oniceconnectionstatechange', pc.iceConnectionState)
  // log checking -> connected -> completed
};
```

---

When i use `firefox` to open it, there is an error `ICE failed, add a STUN server and see about:webrtc for more details` in console.
In `chrome` the 'phone iceConnectionState' changed `checking -> connected -> completed`, the 'web iceConnectionState' changed `checking -> connected`.

Answer (score 1):

have you set `autoplay` in your html? I have the same issue, and it turns out I should have set autoplay in my html tag. Namely:

```
<video autoplay></video>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

getUserMedia is an async function. You are calling createOffer before you call pc.addStream which means there is nothing to negotiate.
Make the promise callback return your pc.createOffer() after pc.addStream(stream);

Answer (score 0):

PTAL at https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#toc-signaling and compare your code to the example and see if you can figure it out.